# Can't open Software-center , google chrome stable newest after installed ibus

Tags: software-center, google-chrome, ibus, elementary

> mr2uang@mr2uang-MS-7798:~$ sudo software-center
>
> ** (software-center:15215): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-f1JihwokKA:
>   Connection refused Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in 
>       from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line
>   51, in 
>       from softwarecenter.backend.ubuntusso import UbuntuSSO   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line
>   29, in 
>       import piston_mini_client.auth   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston_mini_client/**init**.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import httplib2   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 153, in
>   
>       class RelativeURIError(HttpLib2Error): pass TypeError: RelativeURIError() takes exactly 256 arguments (0 given)

and my google chrome keep freezing

> mr2uang@mr2uang-MS-7798:~$ sudo google-chrome
>   [1025/181909:ERROR:nss_util.cc(96)] Failed to create
>   /home/mr2uang/.pki/nssdb directory.

my last installed was

**Vietnamese Input Method Engine for iBus using Unikey**

Comment: cross posting https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2701/cant-open-software-center-google-chrome-stable-newest-after-installed-ibus-vi

Comment: btw what is your Ubuntu version ?

Comment: i'm using elementary os Freya

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so elementary is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at elementary, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**